# map reduce owner did notmat

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

Caused by: java.io.IOException: Owner 'Administrators' for path c:\hadoop\hdfs\m
apred\local\maplogs\taskTracker\Administrator\jobcache\job_201304051800_0003\att
empt_201304051800_0003_m_000000_0\output\file.out.index did not match expected o
wner '

I am trying this on hdinsight  on windows 7 64bit.

This error happened after I changed mapred.local.dir in mapred-site.xml.

How to fix this issue.

Answer (score 0):

try a simple one first : run the job from a CLI as Administrator or alter the permission of tmp dir to be available for everybody